# Using same hbm for multiple databases

Tags: hibernate

We are using hibernate in our project.
We have have 2 databases(ORACLE and MYSQL).
Currently we want to create sequences on oracle, so changes are done on 
hbm to use sequences for generator.
But as same hbm is used when connected to MYSQL and MYSQL doesn't support sequences,
So Is there a way to use same hbm files for both the dbs.

Thanks in advance

Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target Oracle database, you can keep compatibility with 'auto-increment' databases such as MySQL by using the "native" id generator. This also accepts the 'sequence' parameter if you want to name a specific ORACLE sequence. **This is ignored when using a database that supports 'auto-increment' columns**.

```
    <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">MY_ORACLE_SEQUENCE</param>
    </generator>
```